# React App Blocked When Embedded in Iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, iframe, content-security-policy

I am embedding a React-.NET 6 webapp built using the .NET 6 React template. When I run the app, the React UI renders fine. However, when I place the link to the deployed webapp in an iframe, such as `<iframe src="https://myapp.com" title="My app embedded"></iframe>`, I get a blank screen and messages like the following:

In Edge/Chrome: `Refused to frame 'https://myapp.com' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

With the message: `This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue.`

In Firefox: `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://myapp.com (“default-src”).`

Firefox was also just blank in the browser.

I am using `http-proxy-middleware` to allow communication between React and .NET but don't know why I am having this issue or what I can do to resolve it.

I did try adding `"homepage": "."` in my `package.json`, but there was no effect.

I did try changing my `setupProxy.js` file to the following, but there was no effect.

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context, {
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true,
    onProxyRes: function (proxyRes, req, res) {
      proxyRes.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
    },
  });

  app.use(appProxy);
};
```

I do not know where I am making a mistake in the configuration and believe it it a frontend configuration issue, but am not certain it is not a .NET configuration issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a Content Security Policy set on your site, likely a default one, that prevents you from embedding content from other origins. You will need to locate how the Content Security Policy is set and modify it to allow the framing. The current policy seems to be

```
Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self'
```

You'll need to change this to

```
Content-Security-Policy default-src 'self'; frame-src myapp.com;
```